# How to hide the "Navigate" button if the user presses the "Complete Delivery" in Xaml?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am doing an app for the courier service. I am trying to figure out how to hide the "Navigate" button when the user presses the "Complete delivery". I tried some codes but no luck. Thanks in adv!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBCPl.jpg)

// This is the XAML Code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid Padding="10,10,4,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <DatePicker x:Name="dateselector" DateSelected="HandleDateSelected" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></DatePicker>
                <Picker HeightRequest="2" IsVisible="false" Title="ORDERS"  x:Name="ordersfilterpicker" FontSize="Small" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>MY DELIVERIES</x:String>
                        <x:String>FOR PICKUP</x:String>
                        <x:String>RELEASED BY WAREHOUSE</x:String>
                        <x:String>ONGOING</x:String>
                        <x:String>COMPLETED</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>
                <ImageButton Margin="-10,3,0,0" WidthRequest="32" VerticalOptions="Start" BorderColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="5,5,5,5" Clicked="HandleRefreshButton" Source="refresh.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
            <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="False" IsVisible="False" IsEnabled="False" Color="CornflowerBlue" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="80"
                               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1" x:Name="activityind"/>
            <ListView Margin="5,20,5,20" ItemTapped="riderOrdersListView_ItemTapped"  x:Name="riderOrdersListView" ItemsSource="{Binding aorderinfo}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid RowSpacing="5" Padding="0,0,0,0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="55" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <BoxView HeightRequest="25" Color="LightGray" Opacity="0.4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                                <Label Text="REFERENCE NO." Font="Bold,Small" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Label Text="SALES ORDER" Font="Bold,Small" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding checkoutcode}" Font="Bold,Medium" TextColor="#777777" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding salesorderno}" Font="Bold,Medium" TextColor="#777777" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>


                                <BoxView HeightRequest="25" Color="LightGray" Opacity="0.4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                                <Label Text="PICKUP ADDRESS" Font="Bold,Small" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Label Text="DROPOFF ADDRESS" Font="Bold,Small" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding address1}" VerticalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#503026" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding clientaddress}" VerticalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#503026" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>

                                <BoxView HeightRequest="25" Color="LightGray" Opacity="0.4" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                                <Label Text="EXPECTED DELIVERY" Font="Bold,Small" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding requested_deliverytime}" VerticalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#503026" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding status}"  VerticalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="Red" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"/>

                                <BoxView HeightRequest="25" Color="LightGray" Opacity="0.4" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                                <Label Text="ORDER TOTAL" Font="Bold,Small" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Label Text="REMARKS" Font="Bold,Small" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ordertotal,StringFormat='PHP {0:N}'}" VerticalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#503026" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding confirmremarks}" VerticalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#503026" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1"/>

                                <BoxView HeightRequest="25" Color="LightGray" Opacity="0.4" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                                <Label Text="GRAND TOTAL" Font="Bold,Small" TextColor="#777777" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding grandtotal,StringFormat='PHP {0:N}'}" VerticalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" Font="Bold,Small" TextColor="#CCCCCC" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1"/>

                                <Button BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue" BorderRadius="5" Clicked="HandleNavigateButton" Text="NAVIGATE" TextColor="#503026" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Button BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue" BorderRadius="5" Clicked="HandleBookButtonAsync" Text="{Binding buttonlabel}" TextColor="#503026" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

//This is the Code for the buttton for the "Order Complete"

```
async void  HandleBookButtonAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool answer = false;
            var selectedValue = ordersfilterpicker.Items[ordersfilterpicker.SelectedIndex];
            orderinfo tmp_orderinfo = (orderinfo)((Button)sender).BindingContext;
            selectedValue = tmp_orderinfo.status;
            if (selectedValue == "ALL")
            {
                answer = await popup_yesno("ACCEPT this delivery ?");
                if (answer==true)
                {
                    updateorderstatusrideraccept(tmp_orderinfo.checkoutcode);
                    refreshlistviewtask();
                }
            }
            else if (selectedValue == "FOR PICKUP")
            {
                answer = await popup_yesno("START this delivery ?");
                if (answer == true)
                {
                    updateorderstatusriderstart(tmp_orderinfo.checkoutcode);
                    refreshlistviewtask();
                }
            }
            else if (selectedValue == "RELEASED BY LOGISTICS")
            {
                answer = await popup_yesno("START this delivery ?");
                if (answer == true)
                {
                    updateorderstatusriderstart(tmp_orderinfo.checkoutcode);
                    refreshlistviewtask();
                }
            }
            else if (selectedValue == "RELEASED BY WAREHOUSE")
            {
                answer = await popup_yesno("START this delivery ?");
                if (answer == true)
                {
                    updateorderstatusriderstart(tmp_orderinfo.checkoutcode);
                    refreshlistviewtask();
                }
            }
            else if (selectedValue == "ONGOING")
            {
                answer = await popup_yesno("COMPLETE this delivery ?");
                if (answer == true)
                {
                    updateorderstatusriderend(tmp_orderinfo.checkoutcode);
                    refreshlistviewtask();
//I believe I should put something here for the "Nav button" to hide. but I don't know what code to use.                
            }
        }
        //("Message", tmp_orderinfo.checkoutcode, "OK");
    }
```

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  You generally need to show the relevant code in order for us to help you.  And "having trouble" is a very vague description of the problem.  Please provide relevant error messages, code, exceptions, expected vs. actual behavior, etc.  All that said, the general solution is `myControl.IsVisible = false;`

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information. Kindly see the edited post. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try setting the IsVisible property as I suggested?

Comment: oh i havent, will try now.

Comment: Hi, just a clarification, will replace the "myControl" to HandleNavigateButton, because that is the name of my nav button?

Comment: Yes.  You did not post any XAML so I have no idea what your control is actually named

Comment: Hello, I added XAML code, sorry, and thank you for your patience.

Comment: I had test use Button.IsVisible = false to hide the button and it worked well. Did you have a try?

Comment: Hello, I put the "Button.isVisible = false" in the HandleBookButtonAsync button, but it does not work, so I've tried this code. Not working also, may I ask where to put the Button.IsVisible = false? Thank you!

Button.IsVisibleProperty = false;

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should give the button a name with the x:Name. Such as

```
<Button Text="Navigate" Clicked="Button_Clicked" x:Name="button">
```

Then you can set the IsVisible = false in a clicked event. Such as

```
  private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button.IsVisible = false;
    }
```

You can set it in the  the "Complete delivery" pressed event.

Comment: I do follow now, many thanks to you both!

Comment: Has your problem solved? @Robb